# Is there a general manual for the R packages, "quantstrat","blotter","FinancialInstrument" etc. other than the function help files and demos?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, quantstrat, financialinstrument

I'd like to learn how to use these packages, but I cannot seem to find any vignettes that offer something other than extensive code snippets. I'd like to learn about how they all fit together and something akin to a "walk through".

I've found some examples on the web like this series: http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/2011/06/quantstrat-to-build-on.html but I'm after something a bit more in depth (like the vignettes / examples in the package "PerformanceAnalytics"

Any sources?

Answer (score 12):

Guy Yollin at the University of Washington teaches a class which covers some of this in the new [Computational Finance](http://www.amath.washington.edu/studies/computational-finance/) program over there---his lecture notes on quantstrat/blotter can be found at: http://www.r-programming.org/papers

Lastly, recall that these are all packages written by busy volunteers so if documentation is missing ... so maybe you'd want to contribute some yourself?

Comment: I'd be more than happy to once I can figure out how to fit it together! I'm actually writing some stuff for opensource that download, convert and standardize arbitrary amounts of data directly from data vendor APIs (Bloomberg / Reuters / IQFeed / Exchanges etc) or static csv's for use in these types of packages! Very happy to contribute - that's why I'd like to learn more about how to integrate these packages. Thanks for these links and your work on R in general, Dirk!

Comment: +1 for Yollin's lecture notes on quantstrat. They've been incredibly helpful in getting the basics of a system going!

Answer (score 3):

There's a great e-book "Backtesting Strategies with R", written by Tim Trice on that describes the use of `blotter` and `quantstrat` libraries: https://timtrice.github.io/backtesting-strategies/index.html